# Removing connections to network printers that no longer exist

Tags: windows-server-2003, network-printer

I'm trying to delete some network printer connections from a Windows Server 2003 (SP2) machine because the printer shares no longer exist. Windows shows the printers' status as `"Printer not found on server, unable to connect"`; this is expected; the printers are now on a different server. Only one machine ever connected to the printer shares; it no longer needs to and I'd like to clean it up.

However, when I try to delete the connections, I get an error message:

```
---------------------------
Remove Printer
---------------------------
Printer connection cannot be removed. Operation could not be completed.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

The "solutions" I've found online seem to be more voodoo than anything (and they still don't work!). Does anybody know how I can delete these long-gone printers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of years ago I had the same problem and the only thing that worked properly was to locate the relevant registry entries and manually remove them, followed by a reboot.

Comment: I've also had to do this and it worked, don't forget your registry backup ;)

Comment: Yuck. I was hoping not to muck with the registry. Do you have a pointer to the relevant keys?

Comment: As I said, it was a couple of years ago. Just do a search for the printer name and you should find all the entries.